# improper integral convergent , divergent

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

can someone please explain how should i proceed from here?
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sin x} dx$$
I did these steps
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sin x} dx+\int_{1}^{\pi} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sin x} dx$$
and then $$\lim_{x\to\ 0^+}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sin x}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}=\lim_{x\to\ 0^+}\frac{x}{\sin x}=1$$ and therefor first part converge but i stuck here, how should i evaluate second integral? i mean for limit comparison test i don't know to which simpler integral should i compare the second one?
Any help or suggestion would be great

Comment: **Hint:** $\sin x=\sin(\pi-x)$ and $\sin x\approx x$ for small $x$. So $\frac{\sqrt x}{\sin x}\approx \frac\pi{\pi-x}$ for $x$ close to $\pi$. Can you fill in the details and find the conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

In the second integral, write $y=\pi-x$. It becomes
$$\int_0^{\pi-1}\frac{\sqrt{\pi-y}}{\sin y}\,dy$$
and the integrand here is approximately $\sqrt\pi/y$ for $y$ near zero.

Comment: Thank you @ Angina Seng, one question, how did you know that you need to change variable like that ?